# Cordova application doesn't work if JavaScript is in separate file

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap

I want alert window to be shown on button click.
I tried to run it in browser.
Also I tried to do it without jQuery - the same problem.
On my HTML I have just a button:

```
 <html>
<head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <button id="btn">BUTTON</button>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my JavaScript file (no error messages in Chrome's console):

```
function App() {
        var initialize = function () {
            onload();
        }

        onLoad = function () {
            document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            $("#btn").click(
                function () {
                    alert("ALERT");
                }
            );
        }, false);
        }


        onDeviceReady = function () {
            document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
            document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
            document.addEventListener("btn", onMenuKeyDown, false);
        }

        onPause = function () {
        }

        onResume = function () {
        }

        onMenukeyDown = function () {
            $("#btn").click(
                function () {
                    alert("ALERT");
                }
            );

        }
    };
    var app = new App;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand how PhoneGap apps work. They are not websites, so they don't behave like when you run them in your browser. PhoneGap apps run sandboxed in webview which shares a lot of features with web browsers, but has important differences. One important difference is security, which causes the issue that you're experiencing.

You are linking the jQuery library directly from the web. When you run the app on your phone, the webview will block that file, because for security reasons it blocks access to any external website. So you're getting your app with no jQuery.

You have to download the jQuery file into a local folder and changed the link accordingly.

Unrelated to your question, I also recommend loading cordova.js first (before jQuery or any other script).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your index.js syntax. If you have a JavaScript object you need to instantiate like this:

```
 function App() {
        var initialize = function () {
            onload();
        }
        onLoad = function () {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
        }


        onDeviceReady = function () {
            document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
            document.addEventListener("resume", onResume, false);
            document.addEventListener("btn", onMenuKeyDown, false);
        }

        onPause = function () {
        }

        onResume = function () {
        }

        onMenukeyDown = function () {
            $("#btn").click(
                function () {
                    alert("ALERT");
                }
            );

        }
    };
    var app = new App;
```

The deviceready eventlistener only will work if you run your app on mobile device or you can add browser cordova platform to use this way.

But the answer for your question is, simply use jquery. index.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>
    <button id="btn">BUTTON</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
            $("#btn").click(
                function () {
                    alert("ALERT");
                }
            );
        }, false);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I added `var app = new App;` before `app.initialize()`, still nothing on Android. Tried also without .initialize();

Comment: Are you get some errors in console? You can debug with Chrome.

Comment: I'll try last code from edited answer, but for now I have Unexpected identifier on this line: function onLoad() {

Comment: It tells that I  have unexpected identifier on this line: onDeviceReady = function () {

Comment: I edited the last time :). Its works for me. You dont need onload="onLoad()"

Comment: Unexpected token `var` where new App created

Comment: I tried your updated `function App() {` - there no errors in browser, but nothing happens on button click in both Android and browser.

Comment: I didn't have onLoad in html last time. And I tried your javascript embeded into html and it works. But the question is why it's not working while in separate file.

Comment: It has to work if you called your index.js properly: <script src="index.js"></script>. And the  index.js it is placed in the same folder then index.html.

Comment: I tried to move it into the same direcotry and change path. I had "js/index.js" path and it was in "js" directory. I updated my question - there new variant of html and javascript after previous.